# Best way of searching coincidences between 2 tables >1M rows

Tags: mysql, database

I have two very big tables >1M rows each. Basically, What I need to is show results with info of 2 tables mixed when coincidences are found. Simplifing, they both have structure like this:

```
TABLE_A:
-------
id | item_id | some_fields_A


TABLE_B:
-------
id | item_id | some_fields_B
```

As you see, they both have a unique field `item_id`. What I want to do is find which items are in both tables and show `item_id`, `some_fields_A` and `some_fields B`. Id like to know good practices to improve the performance, I have tried with the simple query

```
SELECT item_id, some_fields_A, some_fields_B 
FROM TABLE_A, TABLE_B 
WHERE TABLE_A.item_id = TABLE_B.item_id
```

That shows results after more than 1 hour. I'm using InnoDB engine.

Comment: What did EXPLAIN say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the below work:

```
SELECT a.item_id, a.some_fields_A, b.some_fields_B 
  FROM TABLE_A a 
  INNER JOIN TABLE_B b ON a.item_id = b.item_id;
```

Before execute the query execute below query only once.

```
CREATE INDEX fields_a_idx ON TABLE_A(item_id);
```

And

```
CREATE INDEX fields_b_idx ON TABLE_B(item_id);
```

Means you need to do the indexing for table to increase the performance of query [INDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I guess the best way is to use a INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_a AS A
       INNER JOIN table_b AS B
               ON A.item_id = B.item_id
```

Make sure your item_id's are Primary Keys.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html